# How to check for node-postgres if no results

Tags: node.js, express, node-postgres

I am confused what exactly `node-postgres` postgres database returned if no records ?

```
try {
  const {
    rows: [user]
  } = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE username = $1 LIMIT 1`, [
    username
  ]);

  console.log('user', user);

  if (!user || typeof username !== 'undefined') return false;

  return await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

How to check if there is no user result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `SELECT` query, the [`pg.Result`](https://node-postgres.com/api/result) `rows` is an empty array `[]` with `rows.length === 0`

The `rowCount === 0` as well but this can be different in an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` query where it becomes the updated rows.

Comment: I tested the returned variable in NodeJs, it was `undefined` so I checked `typeof user === 'undefined` BUT for security reasons and Authentication I wanted to know exactly what should I check for .